# Load CKEditor CSS file after custom CSS files in Angular 9

Tags: css, ckeditor, loading, angular9

I have loaded some custom CSS files inside styleUrls array in component hence CKEditor CSS file which is loading after all the custom CSS files is overwriting the custom CSS files. So how to load CKEditor CSS file after all the custom CSS files are loaded in Angular 9?

Comment: how do you know the CKEditor CSS file is loading after ? if you're hard-coding adding the css file in the index html maybe that is your issue, and re-order it there. Or maybe it's because of how you're structuring the HTML. Also try and look at CKEditor theme customisation rather than directly changing the CSS.

Comment: another issue might be how you're updating the css. Are you prefixing it with ::ng-deep ?